# Track where I clicked in ListView MVVM

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am writing a folder browser and I want to open folders on double click.
My folders are binded to ListView with GridView inside and I am tracking double click like this:

```
<i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
                    <Custom:EventToCommand Command="{Binding FolderOpenedCommand, Mode=OneWay}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=FolderView}"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
```

But I have an annoying issue: if I double click on gridview splitter to autosize column, it will also open selected folder, which I am not want to.
So, I have several options for now: put event handler inside style and use it with code behind or leave it as is, but in my case I want to do implement it with MVVM scenario because codebehind is not suitable for me.

My question is: how I can send my parameter as SelectedItem only if I click on the item and null when I click on something else?

I want to track this to make a proper behavior as far as I cannot apply double click to gridview on some reason.

Could someone please help me with this problem?

EDIT:
Lets clarify one thing to be sure we speak about the same things:
I can define something like this

```
<Style x:Key="itemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroListViewItem}">
     <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="FolderView_OnMouseDoubleClick"></EventSetter>
  </Style>
```

Bu I cannot do like this:

```
<Style x:Key="itemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroListViewItem}">
     <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="{Binding OpenFilesCommand}"></EventSetter>
  </Style>
```

Because It will lead to exception. Now I want to understand how I can apply command here if Handler does not accept command? Do I need to write some attached property?

Comment: Your choice of using a `ListView` with a `GridView` is unusual for your requirement... a folder browser is more usually implemented using a `TreeView` control.

Comment: Windows explorer use treview with listview for detail view. I do the same

Comment: Ahh sorry, I thought you were talking about the left hand column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid using listview. Use DataGrid instead. Then you can add eventtrigger to row style. ListView is obsolete class introduced in wpf 3 that was replaced by datagrid in wpf 4 an there no reason to use it anymore.

Another option is to use use custom behaviour implemented as attached property, e.g. InvokeCommandOnRowDoubleClick attached to Grid. To learn more about attached behaviours read this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dgartner/archive/2009/11/11/wpf-attached-behavior-example-watermark-text.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There is a `MouseDoubleClick` property on the `ListViewItem` control. You can rework your style to contain a correct event when double clicking an item, apply it only to the ListViewItems and it won't listen to that event when not double clicking the gridview splitter.

You can read more about this [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb961984%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: I know about that possibility, but as I see there is no way to do it in MVVM scenario. Am I right?

Comment: If you bind your view with your viewmodel there is no reason it shouldn't work. You should be able to use a command from your VM.

Comment: `<Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
    <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="ListViewItem_MouseDoubleClick"/>
</Style>`
its not a MVVM and there is no way to replace Handler with my own command as far as I know

Comment: You can replace the handler with your own command. You can read more about commands in MVVM [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/274982/Commands-in-MVVM).

The principle is the same, expect your view doesn't handle or contain anything for your command, your viewmodel does.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but I dont see how to set command instead of event handler in codebehind. Could you please write here some small exmaple how to achive this? Please.

Comment: The eventhandler in this case is the same as a command. You can set a method in your code behind or in your viewmodel. Like shown in the link in my answer. This handler can be anything, it just fires off whenever you doubleclick a listview item.

Comment: In your event handler you can do this ((ViewModel)sender.DataContext).OpenFilesCommand.Execute(). Its not violation of mvvm principle. Just choose good name for the eventhandler, e.g ExecuteOpenFileComand

Answer (score 0):

Well, to solve this issue I had to use InputBindings property for each control in each gridview column. I put Grid over controls and made like this:

```
<GridViewColumn Header="Size (Bytes)">
              <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                 <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                       <Grid.InputBindings>
                          <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftDoubleClick" Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}, Path=DataContext.FolderOpenedCommand}" 
                                   CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=FolderView, Path=SelectedItem}"></MouseBinding>
                       </Grid.InputBindings>
                       <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Size, StringFormat='{}{0:#,#.}'}"/>
                    </Grid>
                 </DataTemplate>
              </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
           </GridViewColumn>
```

Unfortunately for my case I didnt find better solution